# Java program that reads an integer value and prints the average of all odd integers between 0 and the input value, inclusive

Tags: java, for-loop, math, integer, average

Here is the entire question:

"Write a program that reads an integer value and prints the average of all odd integers between 0 and the input value, inclusive.  Print an error message if the input value is less than 0. Prompt accordingly."

I can't seem to figure out how to get the math to work out in the for loop. I'm having trouble setting it up so that the loop increments in odds. I've tried a million different things and nothing has worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value;
    int oddAvg = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    value = scan.nextInt();

    while (value < 0){
        System.out.println("Error: Input should not be less than 0");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer greater than 0: ");
        value = scan.nextInt();
    }


    for(){

    }


    System.out.println("The average of odd integers between 0 and " + value + " is " + oddAvg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Read more about `arrays` and then give it a try.

Comment: Learn about `modulo` operator.

Comment: @nullpointer This can be solved without using `arrays`.ie. The storing part is not needed.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya how about the `for` loop? what would that iterate on? I know the problem can be solved in another way, just suggesting the OP to read  and try out things before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial approach could be to just iterate from zero to the target number and check whether each number is odd or even:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sum += i;
        count++;
    }
}
int avg = sum / count;
```

But this, of course, is inefficient. A slightly better approach would be to start from the first odd number, `1`, and increment it by `2` in each iteration, so you'd be iterating over just the odd numbers:

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= value; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
    count++;
}
int avg = sum / count;
```

Or, if you want to really be mathematically sound, you can utilize the fact that the odd natural numbers in a given range are uniformly distributed. Since this distribution is symmetric, the average equals the mean, and you don't need a loop at all:

```
int start = 1;
int end = value;
if (value % 2 == 0) { 
    value--;
}
int avg = (end + start) / 2;
```

General comment:
In this specific case the average would be an `int`, so I used `int`s throughout my examples. In the general usecase, you should probably use `double`s to avoid mistakes of using integer division.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much!! Looking at the solution now makes me see how much I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your problem!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 25; //this is whatever value you're going up to.
    int accumulator = 0; //keep track of the total sum
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) { //if odd
            accumulator+=i; // add to the running total sum
        }
    }
    System.out.println(accumulator/(input/2)); //print out the total/num of numbers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if interested in Java 8. It is naive approach implementation.

```
    int val = 0;
    final OptionalDouble average = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, val)
            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
            .average();
    System.out.println(average);
```